# Rotate image with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I just figure out how to rotate image with FFmpeg. But issue is when Filename contain ***"%"*** sign. Then that command not work.

```
ffmpeg -y -i '/mypath/Prat%eek.jpg' -vf transpose=2 '/mypath/Prat%eek.jpg'
```

Comment: why not rename file before conversion, and get it's original name after conversion ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the [documentation of ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/ffprobe-all.html#image2) it is mentioned that each of the special characters `%*?[]{}` should be escaped by `%`.

> All glob special characters %*?[]{} must be prefixed with "%". To escape a literal "%" you shall use "%%".

So the above command, should be

`ffmpeg -y -i '/mypath/Prat%%eek.jpg' -vf transpose=2 '/mypath/Prat%%eek.jpg'`

**EDIT**

After using the above command on linux I found it was not working, and in documentation it is also mentioned that

> For example the pattern foo-%*.jpeg will match all the filenames prefixed by "foo-" and terminating with ".jpeg", and foo-%?%?%?.jpeg will match all the filenames prefixed with "foo-", followed by a sequence of three characters, and terminating with ".jpeg".

So I tried with this command,

`ffmpeg -y -i '/mypath/Prat%?eek.jpg' -vf transpose=2 '/mypath/Prat%%eek.jpg'`

The above command worked.

**Edit**

I did not find in any documentation that source file name should be escaped some other way and destination path should be escaped other way but as per the above command working, I think so,

- All source path should be escaped by using `?` sign (after escape characters) when working with ffmpeg command working on single file.
- Destination path should be escaped by `%` in destination path.